# Error have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Pleas Can anyone explain whats the problem in this?

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.crud.datapegawai, PID: 4989
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.crud.datapegawai/com.crud.datapegawai.AddEdit}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
at com.crud.datapegawai.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DataPegawai">
```

-->

```
    <activity android:name=".list_row" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DataPegawai.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please, add more data about what are you trying to do, and what have done until now. To cut&paste directly the exception doesn't help to identify the root cause. E.g., your error message says your manifest file doesn't containt your activity. Have you included it? Could you attach your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

From the log :

> {com.crud.datapegawai/com.crud.datapegawai.AddEdit}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

It means that there is an activity that you are using, but it was not declared in the android manifest. Every time you create an activity, you also need to declare this activity in the android manifest file. As you can see in your android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".list_row" />
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DataPegawai.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

There is a `<activity>` declaration. So in order to fix your problem, you need to declare `com.crud.datapegawai.AddEdit` in your manifest file. Something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".list_row" />
<activity android:name="com.crud.datapegawai.AddEdit" />
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DataPegawai.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For more details -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro